# Excluding a complete package in Go with build tags

Tags: go

I would like to exclude all files in a package from compilation with the help of [build tags](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints). As far as I know, this has to be done file for file (i.e each excluded file needs to have the `+build` directive at the top or follow the naming convention for GOOS and GOARCH).

So is it possible to exclude a complete package with build tags?

Comment: No. Build constraints apply to the file they're in.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, because if you exclude all files in a package, then it's not a package that be used any longer, and anything referencing it will also fail to build. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: OK. Let me rephrase. I want to have one package that is used when a specific build tag is given and another package that is used when the build tag is not specified.

Comment: So you have the appropriate build tags in the files that _import_ the packages.

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Give a real example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Package build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)
>
> Build Constraints
>
> A build constraint, also known as a build tag, is a line comment that
>   begins
>
> ```
> // +build
> ```
>
> that lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the
>   package.

---

> A build constraint lists the conditions under which a file should be included.

Build constraints operate at the file level.